# Recursive Function To Create Permutations

Tags: scala, recursion

I have the following function which I have checked about a dozen times, and should work exactly as I want, but it ends up with the wrong result.  Can anyone point out what is wrong with this function?

Note:  I'm printing out the list that is being passed in recursive calls; and the list is exactly as I expect it to be.  But the variable called result that accumulates the result does not contain the correct permutations at the end.  Also, I synchronized the access to result variable, but that did NOT fix the problem; so, I don't think synchronization is a problem.  The code can be copied and run as is.

```
import collection.mutable._
def permute(list:List[Int], result:StringBuilder):Unit =
{
    val len = list.size
    if (len  == 0) (result.append("|"))
    else
    {   
        for (i <- 0 until len )
        {
            println("========" + list + "===========")
            result.append( list(i) )
            if (i != len -1) 
            {
                //println("Adding comma since i is: " + i)
                result.append(", ")
            }   
            //println("******** Reslut is:" + result + "***********")
            permute( (sublist(list, i) ), result)               
        }   
    }   

    // This function removes just the ith item, and returns the new list.
    def sublist (list:List[Int], i:Int): List[Int] =
    {
        var sub:ListBuffer[Int] = (list.map(x => x)).to[ListBuffer]
        sub.remove(i)
        return sub.toList
    }
}

var res = new StringBuilder("")
permute(List(1,2,3), res)
println(res)
```

The output is:

```
========List(1, 2, 3)===========
========List(2, 3)===========
========List(3)===========
========List(2, 3)===========
========List(2)===========
========List(1, 2, 3)===========
========List(1, 3)===========
========List(3)===========
========List(1, 3)===========
========List(1)===========
========List(1, 2, 3)===========
========List(1, 2)===========
========List(2)===========
========List(1, 2)===========
========List(1)===========
**1, 2, 3|32|2, 1, 3|31|31, 2|21|**
```

Comment: What is the java tag doing here?

Comment: Java and Scala are not that different, and this is about recursion problem, rather than syntax problem.

Comment: Not that different ? Hem... allow me to contradict you.

Comment: Why did you believe synchronizing anything could be helpful ? There's no concurrency in the code you shared.

Comment: You're also not explaining what you're trying to do, and what is the expected output

Comment: You are correct there is no synchronization.  I just wanted to make sure Scala doesn't by any chance runs the code on different cores.

Comment: Observation on the side as I read the code: `apply(Int)` is extremely inefficient on a `List`, you should never iterate on a Scala list like this.

Comment: It's simple; given a list of numbers, I want  to generate all the possible permutations of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Dici's solution is good, but kind of cryptic. I think the following code is much more clear:

```
def permutations(list: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = list match
{
    case Nil | _::Nil => List(list)
    case _ =>(  
        for (i <- list.indices.toList) yield
        {
            val (beforeElem, afterElem) = list.splitAt(i)
            val element = afterElem.head
            val subperm = permutations (beforeElem ++ afterElem.tail)
            subperm.map(element:: _)
        }   
    ).flatten
}

val result = permutations(List (1,2,3,4,5) )
println(result.mkString("\n") )
```

The output will be:

```
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 3, 2)
List(2, 1, 3)
List(2, 3, 1)
List(3, 1, 2)
List(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Why do you think your solution is clearer ? To me it does the exact same thing in slightly more lines, mainly because you don't leverage pattern matching on lists. I think they both read quite easily

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your approach, the main one being that you don't actually implement the recurrence relation between the permutations of `n` elements and the permutations of `n + 1` elements, which is that you can take all permutations of `n` elements and insert the `n + 1`th element at every position of every permutation of `n` elements to get all the permutations of `n + 1` elements.

One way to do it, more Scalatically, is:

```
def sortedPermutations(list: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = list match {
  case Nil | _ :: Nil => List(list)
  case _              => list.indices.flatMap(i => list.splitAt(i) match { 
    case (head, t :: tail) => sortedPermutations(head ::: tail).map(t :: _)
  }).toList
}

println(sortedPermutations(List(1, 2, 3)).map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("|"))
```

Output:

```
1,2,3|1,3,2|2,1,3|2,3,1|3,1,2|3,2,1
```

Note that this is very inefficient though, because of all the list concatenations. An efficient solution would be tail-recursive or iterative. I'll post that a bit later for you.